# Web Services on UDP

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, udp

I need to convert an existing Web Service (done on .Net 2.0) which runs on SOAP/HTTP to run on UDP.

I found a ton of resources on web on explaining why and how I should go about doing it. But all of them too general.

Can someone point me to a example/resource of some sort specific to .Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can switch to WCF (available in .NET 3.0 and up), you could do that. In WCF 3.0/3.5, you have to use one of the several implementations of UDP as a transport protocol available from the community (e.g. see [Waleed Mohamed's excellent series](http://waleedmohamed.net/?s=How+to+Implement+UDP+as+a+custom+WCF+Transport&submit=Search) on building a UDP binding for WCF).

If I'm not mistaken, the UdpBinding will also be part of the upcoming WCF in .NET 4.0 (to be released sometime before the end of 2009, as Microsoft promises) - so in .NET 4.0, you'll probably be able to use UDP as transport protocol in WCF right out of the box.

Marc

Comment: Waleeds blog entries on Udp binding for WCF was indeed helpful. Thank you very much!

Comment: But raw UDP is unreliable. What about such applications which reliability is required?